# UWP/WinRT equivalent of NSDataDetector

Tags: ios, windows-runtime, uwp, nsdatadetector

I'm porting a feature from an iOS app over to a Windows 10 UWP app that requires URLs to be detected in strings (so that I can present the URL part as clickable in the view). In iOS the NSDataDetector API works great for this, but I have not found the equivalent API for a UWP app. Does such an API exist?

Thanks!
-Tom B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Window Runtime and .NET Class Library does not have such kind of API.

As I see from the document:

> The NSDataDetector class is a specialized subclass of the
>   NSRegularExpression class designed to match data detectors.

In the .NET Framework, there is a class named Regex.

Document: [.NET Framework Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can implement the similar functionality based on the Regex class in UWP development.